# dll works fine in a VS2010 project but gives access violations in a VS6 Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, access-violation, visual-studio-6

I have been creating a dll for a usb device over the past few weeks, the device came with its own dll which i used to create my own dll in VS2010, I then created a test application which uses said dll in 2010 to get it working. It works well, however I now need to use it in a VS6 project, when i use it I get access violations, I recreated the dll in VS6 to see if that would help, it allowed me to step into the code, as soon as it gets to a line in my dll that calls the 3rd party dll, it causes an access violation, I have just tried creating a factory function to create a abstract interface to my dll but I again get access violations. I am new to dlls and am completely out of ideas, and help or insight would be greatly appritiated...

Comment: If you're passing or returning values from the exported DLL functions, those values must be generic Window's types such as `LONG`, `DWORD`, `BOOL`, etc. and pointers to those types.  If you're passing around C++ classes, then you're out of luck.  You need to compile everything for VS6.

Comment: I.e. in C++ interfaces between dll's are not binary compatible.

Comment: you're mixing the runtime libraries, it is bad. For your case, it is very bad as from VC6 to VS2010, there're a lot of difference between VC6 runtime and VS2010 runtime. VC 6 is really very old, your third party DLL should not be written in VC6 either.  You may need update the VC 6 project to VC 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you can get a DLL created with a later version of Visual Studio to work with Visual Studio 6 is to code your DLL in a generic way in terms of parameters passed and returned to the DLL's exported functions.

For example, the Windows API describes certain variable types.  These types include `DWORD`, `LONG`, `BOOL`, `DWORD_PTR`, etc.  Included are the various string pointer types such as `LPCSTR`.  Also included in this list are pointers to these various types such as `LPLONG`, `LPBYTE`, `LPVOID` etc.

If your DLL's exported functions passes or returns a type that isn't one of the above, then you're stuck -- the DLL can only be used safely in an application that was built with the same version of Visual Studio that the DLL was built with.

For example, if you're passing C++ objects (standard library objects, or even your own objects), that is a big no-no if you want that DLL to work across several versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I have a few more thing to try now :), Is it okay for the dll to use C++ objects within itself? as long as it doesn't try to pass, and return those variables without converting them back to one of those types first then?

Comment: @PerryWard The good thing is that the DLL can use anything internally (templates, exceptions, STL, boost, etc.).